# How to change the List of items to lower in C#?

Tags: c#, xml

```
XDocument.Load(@"C:xxx.xml");   
        var EnList = doc.Descendants("MasterCode")                      
        .Where(element => (string)element.Element("Category") == "LastName")
        .Select(x => x.Element("Name").Value).ToList();   
        String[] splitedTest = EnList.ToLower().Split(' ');
```

I am getting this error in to lower.
There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'destination' of 'MemoryExtensions.ToLower(ReadOnlySpan, Span, CultureInfo?)'

THIS is my xml file:

```
<MasterCode>
    <Uid>119</Uid>
    <Name>Juan Gabriel MONTE</Name>
    <Category>LastName</Category>
  </MasterCode>
<MasterCode>
    <Uid>120</Uid>
    <Name>Atilla SELEK</Name>
    <Category>FirstName</Category>
  </MasterCode>
 <MasterCode>
    <Uid>121</Uid>
    <Name>barbosa filisa</Name>
    <Category>LastName</Category>
  </MasterCode>
```

Comment: anyone help me to clear the error in TO LOWER ,

Comment: You have typo From : Descendants("MeCode")  to Descendants("MasterCode")

Comment: sorry when i posted question here the typo came in.

Comment: im getting that error while changing to lower can anyone help?

Comment: It is a list : String[] splitedTest = EnList.Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToArray();

Comment: split option is missing? I also want the split option to be there

Comment: What do you want to split?

Comment: the same list which we are changing to lower.So i can take it as token item.I just want the split option also to be added.

Comment: So results will be string[][]? A double array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first off, your XML file can't have multiple of the same root elements, you have to have another element wrapping all those 'MasterCode' elements.

Secondly, I'm assuming that you're loading the XML file into the 'doc' variable.
If so then take a look at the below solution, the reason you're getting the error you're getting is because you're trying to call .ToLower() on a list of a list of strings (List < List< string >>) instead of calling it on a list of strings.

***TLDR*** Take note of line 5:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(@"XMLFile1.xml");
        System.Collections.Generic.List<string> EnList = doc.Descendants("MasterCode")
        .Where(element => (string)element.Element("Category") == "LastName")
        .Select(x => x.Element("Name").Value).ToList();
        string[] splitedTest = EnList.Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToArray();
```